# Enum-like arguments in R

Tags: r, enums

I'm new to R and I'm currently trying to supply the enumeration-like argument to the R function (or the RC/R6 class method), I currently use character vector plus `match.arg` similar to the following:

```
EnumTest = function(enum = c("BLUE", "RED", "BLACK")) {
  enumArg <-
    switch(
      match.arg(enum), "BLUE" = 0L, "RED" = 1L, "BLACK" = 2L
    )
  switch(enumArg,
         # do something
  )
}
```

Is there are better/more concise way to imitate enum-like behavior in R? E.g. one big problem that user has to know the set of possible values for the argument and manually type it as a string - without any suggestion or auto-completion...

If there is no other better way, one thing that could improve above approach - it'd be nice to make it more concise by say predefining enums globally or say as private members of R6 class:

```
Color <- c("BLUE", "RED", "BLACK")
```

Then one could (re)use it in one or more function definitions, e.g.:

```
EnumTest = function(enum = Color) { 
...
```

However, I'm not sure how to use this `Color` vector in `match.arg` function. It'd be nice if I could define `Color` as a map with keys being actual color values and values being integer representation - but I'm not sure how sensible that is.. Anyways, maybe there are more common neat approaches exist.

The main goal would be to provide an easy-to-use intuitive interface to the user of my package and functions (e.g. easy way to find the set of possible values, tab-completion, auto-suggestion, etc..), followed by standardized development of such functions using enum-like arguments

Comment: What about factors? THey are basically built-in enums

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Could you please expand or provide example if possible? I've looked at factors briefly but didn't noticed how they can be better in above arguments task.. there is a huge chance that I missed something

Comment: Yes, I understand this. My question is how to properly use them for argument passing... If I define say `func <- function(enum = factor(c("a", "b", "c"))` and user calls `func(enum = "a")`, then inside the function `enum` argument is just a character.. I'm not sure if it's even possible to get the int representation of it

Comment: @OlegShirokikh and how it is worse than what you have now with array of chars? It is clearly better, factors have levels and order, and you could convert from underlying integer to string and back, etc.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's worse :) Just trying to understand... how to properly use them in this particular case

Comment: I would make factor Color and put it into enclosing environment. Passing in/out either ints or strings and verify them against Color factor, convert to/from int using it, basically as you stated `It'd be nice if I could define Color as a map with keys being actual color values and values being integer representation`

Comment: ok, thanks. although i'm not sure how to `verify them against Color factor, convert to/from int using it` efficiently/concisely

Answer (score 14):

How about using a function that defines the enum by returning `list(a= "a", ...)`? You can then either assign the returned vector to a variable and use it in context, or use the function directly. Either a name or an integer reference will work as an index, although you have to use the unlist version of the index lookup, `[[`, otherwise you get a list with one element.

```
colorEnum <- function() {
    list(BLUE = "BLUE", RED = "RED", BLACK = "BLACK")
}

colorEnum()$BLUE
#> [1] "BLUE"
colorEnum()[[1]]
#> [1] "BLUE"
colorEnum()[1]
#> $BLUE
#> [1] "BLUE"

col <- colorEnum()
col$BLUE
#> [1] "BLUE"
col[[1]]
#> [1] "BLUE"
col$BAD_COLOR
#> NULL
col[[5]]
#> Error in col[[5]] : subscript out of bounds
```

You can get the list of names for use in a match, i.e. your function parameter could be

```
EnumTest = function( enum = names(colorEnum()) { ...
```

You can actually abbreviate too, but it must be unique. (If you use RStudio, since `col` is a list, it will suggest completions!)

```
col$BLA
#> [1] "BLACK"
col$BL
#> NULL
```

If you want more sophisticated enum handling, you could assign S3 classes to the thing returned by your enum constructor function and write a small collection of functions to dispatch on class "enum" and allow case-insensitive indexing. You could also add special functions to work with a specific class, e.g. "colorEnum"; I have not done that here. Inheritance means the list access methods all still work.

```
colorEnum2 <- function() {
    structure(
        list(BLUE = "BLUE", RED = "RED", BLACK = "BLACK"),
        class= c("colorEnum2", "enum", "list")
    )
}

# Note, changed example to allow multiple returned values.
`[.enum` <- function(x, i) {
    if ( is.character( i ))
        i <- toupper(i)
    class(x) <- "list"
    names(as.list(x)[i])
}

`[[.enum` <- function(x, i, exact= FALSE) {
    if ( is.character( i ))
        i <- toupper(i)
    class(x) <- "list"
    as.list(x)[[i, exact=exact]]
}

`$.enum` <- function(x, name) {
    x[[name]]
}

col <- colorEnum2()
# All these return [1] "RED"
col$red
col$r
col[["red"]]
col[["r"]]
col["red"]

col[c("red", "BLUE")]
#> [1] "RED" "BLUE"

col["r"]
[1] NA   # R does not matches partial strings with "["
```

These override the built in `[`, `[[` and `$` functions when the thing being indexed is of class "enum", for any "enum" classed objects. If you need another one, you just need to define it.

```
 directionEnum <- function() {
    structure(
        list(LEFT = "LEFT", RIGHT = "RIGHT"),
        class= c("directionEnum", "enum", "list")
    )
}

directionEnum()$l
#> [1] "LEFT"
```

If you need several enum objects, you could add a factory function `enum` that takes a vector of strings and a name and returns an `enum` object. Most of this is just validation.

```
enum <- function(enums, name= NULL) {
    if (length(enums) < 1)
        stop ("Enums may not be empty." )
    enums <- toupper(as.character(enums))
    uniqueEnums <- unique(enums)
    if ( ! identical( enums, uniqueEnums ))
        stop ("Enums must be unique (ignoring case)." )
    validNames <- make.names(enums)
    if ( ! identical( enums, validNames ))
       stop( "Enums must be valid R identifiers." )

    enumClass <- c(name, "enum", "list")
    obj <- as.list(enums)
    names(obj) <- enums
    structure( obj, class= enumClass)
}

col <- enum(c("BLUE", "red", "Black"), name = "TheColors")
col$R
#> [1] "RED"
class(col)
#> [1] "TheColors" "enum"      "list"

side <- enum(c("left", "right"))
side$L
#> [1] "LEFT"
class(side)
#> [1] "enum" "list"
```

But now this is starting to look like a package...

Answer (score 13):

I like to use environments as replacement for enums because you can lock them to prevent any changes after creation. I define my creation function like this:

```
Enum <- function(...) {

  ## EDIT: use solution provided in comments to capture the arguments
  values <- sapply(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)[-1L], deparse)

  stopifnot(identical(unique(values), values))

  res <- setNames(seq_along(values), values)
  res <- as.environment(as.list(res))
  lockEnvironment(res, bindings = TRUE)
  res
}
```

Create a new enum like this:

```
FRUITS <- Enum(APPLE, BANANA, MELON)
```

We can the access the values:

```
FRUITS$APPLE
```

But we cannot modify them or create new ones:

```
FRUITS$APPLE <- 99  # gives error
FRUITS$NEW <- 88  # gives error
```

Comment: You can replace your hack with this: `values <- sapply(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)[-1L], deparse)`

Comment: Indeed, that is much better! Thank you for your comment. I have included your solution in the answer.

Comment: @EAF -> I really like this enum approach (especially the fact that it is locked and cannot be reassigned after creation), but I was wondering if I could add a named argument to the function where I can TAG the enum ID ... something like ```function(enumID='eTestEnum', ...) { [standard code logic]; print(paste0("Created a new Enumerated Data Class called => '", enumID,"'."); return(res); }``` . That way I can have a print function inside the main function to let the user know what the ID or name of the newly created enum is or was. Does that question make sense?

Comment: @SilSur Yes, that is certainly possible. You just need to create a function that prints/uses the `enumID` within the environment that is returned by the `Enum()` function. Since the ID is captured in the closure, it will work as intended. However, it has the side effect that the enum now has a new member that is actually a function. But I don't see how you could handle it otherwise with this approach.

Comment: @SilSur I rejected your edit because it was not my intention to make the `Enum()` function work only with uppercase arguments. This is a stylistic choice that, imo, should be left to the caller of the function.

Comment: @AEF - I believe the 'toupper()' wrap is not as much a stylistic choice as it is a code accuracy fix ... because if you don't set the same case for all enum values before running the 'identical()' check then the check might fail. As an example try the following case: ```EEZs <- Enum(AFRICA, USA, AfriCA, Usa, uSA, Europe)```. If you don't set all these enum values here to the same case (either upper or lower) then the ```stopifnot(identical(unique(values), values))``` check will not catch the duplication. Please try the code & see for yourself. Is that how you intended the code to work?

Comment: @SilSur yes, that's how it's intended. If someone wants 'AFRICA' and 'AfriCA' as separate values that should be allowed. Also, the answer is intended to give the prototype of an enum that can be extended as needed. I could think of many additional functions (eg. assigning numbers that can be used as flags) and checks that would make the enum better for lots of use-cases, but the answer should just show the basics and leave room for adaption. Too much implemented functionality obscurs the main point (in the context of an SO answer).

Comment: @AEF - Alright. Fair enough. I thought enum values were meant to be unique, clear and unambiguous.

Comment: @SilSur yes, of course they should be. But that can also be achieved when they are all lowercase. Or all CamelCase. Or any other consistent possibility. You are right, one should choose a style and stick to it, maybe even enforce it, but an answer on how to create an enum should not decide on that. Ultimately an enum is what the name suggests: A fixed enumeration of values. Everything additional may be good practice, but obscures the main point: How to create locked environments as replacement for enums. From this basis everyone can easily add what they need.

Answer (score 4):

I just faced this exact problem and could only find this SO question. The objectProperties package mention by Paul seems abandoned (it produces several warnings) and has lots of overhead for such a simple (in principle) problem. I came up with the following lightweight solution (depends only on the `stringi` package), which reproduces the feel of Enums in C languages. Maybe this helps someone.

```
EnumTest <- function(colorEnum = ColorEnum$BLUE) {
  enumArg <- as.character(match.call()[2])
  match.arg(enumArg, stringi::stri_c("ColorEnum$", names(ColorEnum)))
  sprintf("%s: %i",enumArg,colorEnum)
}

ColorEnum <- list(BLUE = 0L, RED = 1L, BLACK = 2L)
```

Comment: Is this introspecting the actual invocation of the method to ensure that the integer supplied is from ColorEnum and not just a raw integer?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple method which supports enums with assigned values or which use the name as the value by default:

```
makeEnum <- function(inputList) {
  myEnum <- as.list(inputList)
  enumNames <- names(myEnum)
  if (is.null(enumNames)) {
    names(myEnum) <- myEnum
  } else if ("" %in% enumNames) {
    stop("The inputList has some but not all names assigned. They must be all assigned or none assigned")
  }
  return(myEnum)
}
```

If you are simply trying to make a defined list of names and don't care about the values you can use like this:

```
colors <- makeEnum(c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

If you wish, you can specify the values:

```
hexColors <- makeEnum(c(red="#FF0000", green="#00FF00", blue="#0000FF"))
```

In either case it is easy to access the enum names because of code completion:

```
> hexColors$green
[1] "#00FF00"
```

To check if a variable is a value in your enum you can check like this:

```
> param <- hexColors$green
> param %in% hexColors
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update 07/21/2017: I have created a package for enumerations in R:**

https://github.com/aryoda/R_enumerations

---

If you want to use self-defined **enum-alike data types as arguments of R functions** that support

- automatic translation of enum item names to the corresponding integer values
- code auto completion (e. g. in RStudio)
- clear documentation in the function signature which values are allowed as actual function parameters
- easy validation of the actual function parameter against the allowed (integer) enum item values

you can define your own `match.enum.arg` function, e. g.:

```
match.enum.arg <- function(arg, choices) {
  if (missing(choices)) {
    formal.args <- formals(sys.function(sys.parent()))
    choices <- eval(formal.args[[as.character(substitute(arg))]])
  }

  if(identical(arg, choices))
    arg <- choices[[1]][1]    # choose the first value of the first list item

  allowed.values <- sapply(choices,function(item) {item[1]})   # extract the integer values of the enum items

  if(!is.element(arg, allowed.values))
    stop(paste("'arg' must be one of the values in the 'choices' list:", paste(allowed.values, collapse = ", ")))

  return(arg)
}
```

**Usage:**

You can then define and use your own enums like this:

```
ColorEnum <- list(BLUE = 1L, RED = 2L, BLACK = 3L)

color2code = function(enum = ColorEnum) { 
  i <- match.enum.arg(enum)
  return(i)
}
```

**Example calls:**

```
> color2code(ColorEnum$RED) # use a value from the enum (with auto completion support)
[1] 2
> color2code()              # takes the first color of the ColorEnum
[1] 1
> color2code(3)             # an integer enum value (dirty, just for demonstration)
[1] 3
> color2code(4)             # an invalid number
Error in match.enum.arg(enum) : 
  'arg' must be one of the values in the 'choices' list: 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: What I don't understand is why do this at all?  How does a python like enum differ in practice from an R factor?  They seem like they're the same, though I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: @BenG R has no such thing like an "enum", only factors which offer numeric to string translations and other simple things. If you want to know more about the differences I suggest you open a new question (if non already exists for this topic) to avoid "highjacking" this question. BTW: For a good spec on Python enums see the PEP document: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/