# R Proper checking of supplied parameters against a list of values?

Tags: r, list, function, arguments, optional-arguments

In one comment to the [accepted answer on how to "correctly" specify optional arguments in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28370319/1113697), @LouisMaddox said

> `missing()` is useless when you want to use proper checking of supplied parameters against a list though. For a function `Foo` with parameter `bar` and optional switch `a_or_b` (default value "a") you can write `Foo <- function(bar, a_or_b=c("a", "b"))` ...

Is there a proper/recommended/idiomatic way for checking supplied parameters against a  list of possible values?

I tried to look at `graphics::plot.default` and also glimpsed at `graphics::par` but couldn't make anything intelligible from these two functions (to see how the `type` parameter is handled for example).

In the case of the `type` parameter for example, all possible values are one-letter strings, so I guess somewhere, there's a big `switch` statement or a bunch of `if` statements.

Comment: There was a similar discussion here and I have created a small package for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42987798/4468078

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a small number of options then use `match.arg` within the function.  See `?match.arg` for an example.

If the valid argument is all one letter strings then you will need to another approach such as:

```
# returns logical 
is_one_letter_string <- function(x) {
     !missing(x) && length(x) == 1 && is.character(x) && x %in% c(letters, LETTERS)
}
```

Comment: Your answer is enough for the question, thanks. I need more info on how to do polymorphic stuff in R (to reduce the use of a big switch statement in a few use cases) but that's for some time later.

Comment: Try this: `myfun <- function(x, ...) if (is_one_letter_string(x)) do.call(paste0("run_", x), list(...))` assuming you have functions `run_a`, `run_b`, etc.